# existence of particular row in datatable in vb.net windows form

Tags: vb.net

Is it possible to check for existence of a particular row in a datatable?
suppose if there are two rows in datatable, is it possible to check whether the third row exists or not?

```
For j As Integer = 0 To dtemp.Rows.Count - 1
If dtemp.Rows(j)("empcode").ToString.Trim <> dt.Rows(j)("empcode").ToString.Trim Then
'Insert code  
End If  
Next
```

Comment: i am trying to compare values in two datatable  

For j As Integer = 0 To dtemp.Rows.Count - 1  
If dtemp.Rows(j)("empcode").ToString.Trim <> dt.Rows(j)("empcode").ToString.Trim Then  
'Insert values
End If  
Next  

here dtemp has 3 rows and dt has 2 rows, so i want to check whether dt datatable has 3rd row.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to see if your data is existing or not?

Let's say: If you are inserting data in your database, then you can use the textbox property tag to see whether the data is existing or not.

```
If Me.txtFirstName.Tag = 0 Then
                sSQL = "INSERT INTO tblAddressBook ( last_name, first_name, mid_name, birth_date, gender, home_adr, bus_adr, tel_no, mobile_no, email)"
                sSQL = sSQL & "  VALUES(@last_name, @first_name, @mid_name, @birth_date, @gender, @home_adr, @bus_adr, @tel_no, @mobile_no, @email)"
                cmd.CommandText = sSQL
            Else
                sSQL = "UPDATE tblAddressBook set last_name = @last_name, first_name =  @first_name, mid_name =  @mid_name, birth_date = @birth_date, gender = @gender"
                sSQL = sSQL & " ,home_adr = @home_adr, bus_adr = @bus_adr, tel_no = @tel_no, mobile_no = @mobile_no, email =  @email where contact_id = @id"
                cmd.CommandText = sSQL
            End If
```

...or else it will update that data in your database. The code above should give you an idea. SINCE you didn't show your code let's talk on this one.

Comment: i am trying to compare values in two datatable 
For j As Integer = 0 To dtemp.Rows.Count - 1 
If dtemp.Rows(j)("empcode").ToString.Trim <> dt.Rows(j)"empcode").ToString.Trim Then 
'Insert values 
End If 
Next 
here dtemp has 3 rows and dt has 2 rows, so i want to check whether dt datatable has 3rd row.

Answer (score 0):

If DataRow.Table.Columns.Contains("column") Then
        MsgBox("YAY")
    End If

Comment: I want to check existance of a row. The above code throws an error
"Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference."